# how to gsub "/" and "\" from mutiple cols

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

[image]

I want to clean it up by two method:

1. `gsub` the subject 1-4 if it started with `\` or `/` to `""`;
   or
2. change all `/` to `\`, and add `\` to the one that is not start with `\`.

Is it a way to do this  using `mutate(across(everything(),...)` or any other way?

I would like to know how to achieve both methods if it is possible. Thanks.

The ideal output will looks like this:

[image]

sample data:

```
df<- structure(list(ID = c("Tom", "Jerry"), Subject1 = c("/Art", "/ELA"
), Subject2 = c("\\Math", "/Math"), Subject3 = c("PE", "\\Bio\\2"
), Subject4 = c(NA, "\\Music\\1")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may match any character that are not a letter from the start (`^`) and remove it with `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with("Subject"), 
   ~ str_remove(.x, "^[^[:alpha:]]+")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  ID    Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4  
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     
1 Tom   Art      Math     "PE"      <NA>     
2 Jerry ELA      Math     "Bio\\2" "Music\\1"
```

---

Or escape the `\\`

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("Subject"), ~ str_remove(.x, "^(/|\\\\)")))
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  ID    Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4  
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     
1 Tom   Art      Math     "PE"      <NA>     
2 Jerry ELA      Math     "Bio\\2" "Music\\1"
```

or can also be

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("Subject"), ~ str_remove(.x, "^[/\\\\]")))
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  ID    Subject1 Subject2 Subject3 Subject4  
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     
1 Tom   Art      Math     "PE"      <NA>     
2 Jerry ELA      Math     "Bio\\2" "Music\\1"
```

---

For the second case, it would be to use `str_replace`

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Subject"), 
  ~ str_replace(str_replace(.x, "^\\\\", "/"), "^([A-Z])", "/\\1")))

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  ID    Subject1 Subject2 Subject3  Subject4   
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>      
1 Tom   /Art     /Math    "/PE"      <NA>      
2 Jerry /ELA     /Math    "/Bio\\2" "/Music\\1"
```

Comment: Thanks. This fulfilled the goal of method 1. any idea how to achieve method 2?

Comment: @akun Thanks for method 2. but it missed the case when `Subjectx` is start with letter, like Tom's `Subject3`. If I want all `Subject` start with `/`, what should I do. I can do add `/` to all  and then replace "//" to "/". but I think there might be a better way.

Comment: @Stataq try the update now.  thanks.  I didn't see that part earlier.

Comment: @akun Thanks. Could you explain ` "/\\1"` part? if a string start with letter, then?

Comment: @Stataq I did that in two steps i. inner str_replace replace the beginning `\\` with `/` and the outer one, matches the upper case letters ([A-Z]`) at the start (`^`), capture as a group (`(...)`) and then in the replacement add the `/` followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group i.e. the letter